# What data structure to use in Java for adding objects and using subList

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a class `Gerbil` that I use to test my code. In main I want to make an array of type `Gerbil` and then perform some operations on it starting with creating a sublist from the main list of objects. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Gerbil> hs = new ArrayList<Gerbil>();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            hs.add(new Gerbil(i));
        }
        for(Gerbil i : hs) {
            i.hop();
        }

    }
}
```

I get error for `List<Gerbil>` saying that `The type List is ont of generic type..`. I understand the meaning of the error but that makes me wonder what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `java.util.List` from the Collections API:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have imported java.awt.List, a non-generic UI component for *displaying* a number of items and allowing a user to choose one or more, instead of java.util.List, a generic interface covering indexable collections.

You might need a short spell outside an IDE to get you used to what imports do.

Comment: Thanks, I use Eclipse and mostly the auto-import when I have an error of such kind, but this time the IDE confused me.